# System Argument out of range exception in C# while adding rows to datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a code as follows:

```
private void svars_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {



            userSelection user_sel = new userSelection();
            string file = svars.SelectedItem.ToString();

            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();



            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

            row.Cells["Local_Variables"].Value = "test";

            DataGridViewCell sysvar = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            sysvar.Value = file;
            row.Cells["System_Variables"] = sysvar;

        }
```

I am getting error following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

When I tried to debug I found that row.Index is -1. I am not sure how to fix it. Can anyone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how to view this but as soon as program  reads this  row.Cells["Local_Variables"].Value = "test"; it gives the error.

Comment: Cells["Local_Variables"] returns null meaning that you don't have a column named `Local_Variables`.

Comment: i have problem with row index not the cells. row index value is -1.

Answer (score 2):

The `Cell`s "Local_Variables" and "System_Variables" do not exist in `row.Cells`.  Make sure you first add them.

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Local_Variables", "Local Variables");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("System_Variables", "Local Variables");
```

If the columns are already there, then check their `Key` values to ensure that they're set properly.

Comment: It gives me error "No overload for method 'Add' takes '2' arguments.

Comment: Again I am getting an error does not contain definition for Columns.